# Is it possible to have biztalk 2013 to write to an azure queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Currently we have Biztalk 2013 set up to write to Azure Blob storage using its WCF service. This is available out of the box.

However, is there a way to have Biztalk 2013 write to an azure queue instead?

Comment: Did you see this example for BizTalk 2010: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-integrate-a-BizTalk-1079811b ?

Comment: @r3verse a service bus queue is different than a storage queue

Comment: Ah you mean Azure Queue Storage then? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message. It's just a REST service so you should be fine with the BizTalk http binding.